# How can I add color,bg permanently with local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

My motive is that when a user will click on the button then the button's background color and text color will be changed permanently. When I click on the button then colors are perfectly added, but not permanently. When I reload the browser page, the color also goes removed. How can I fix it?

***index.html:***

```
<body>
    <button class="clickFirst" onclick="click1()">click1</button>
    <input type="color" id="colorID" oninput="changeColor()">
</body>
```

***style.css:***

```
<style>
    .style1{
      background-color: green;
      color: white;
    }
    .style2{
      background-color: blue;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
```

***index.js:***

```
function click1(){
    localStorage.setItem("class1","style1");
    green = localStorage.getItem("class1");

    var b1 = document.querySelector(".clickFirst");
    b1.classList.add(green);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get color value from localStorage and set it to your element (button) at the beginning of your program

Answer (score 0):

You are close. Change your javascript code to apply the color when the page loads

I have modified your js code a bit to reflect that

> the code will not work here because stackoverflow does not allow access to localStorage as its a sandbox

```js
function applyColors() {
  green = localStorage.getItem("class1");
  var b1 = document.querySelector(".clickFirst");
  b1.classList.add(green);
}

function storeColor() {
  localStorage.setItem("class1", "style1");
  applyColors();
}

(function () {
  applyColors();
})();
```

```css
  .style1{
      background-color: green;
      color: white;
    }
    .style2{
      background-color: blue;
      color: white;
    }
```

```html
<button class="clickFirst" onclick="click1()">click1</button>
<input type="color" id="colorID" oninput="changeColor()">
```

Comment: It has given me this error,,,,,, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
    at applyColors (index.js:27:8)
    at index.js:36:5
    at index.js:37:5

Comment: @Mossaddak there is no classList in my answer code nor in your question code. This is not mentioned here

Answer (score 0):

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("button")
const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")

btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (body[0].style.backgroundColor === "white") {
        body[0].style.backgroundColor = "black"
        body[0].style.color = "white"


    } else {
        body[0].style.backgroundColor = "white"
        body[0].style.color = "black"


    }
    localStorage.setItem("bgColor", body[0].style.backgroundColor)
    localStorage.setItem("textColor", body[0].style.color)
})
body[0].style.backgroundColor = localStorage.getItem("bgColor")
body[0].style.color = localStorage.getItem("textColor")
```